# Quitient of two infinite-dimentional groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it possible that quotient group G/H  will be **finite**-dimensional while G and H are **infinite**-dimensional? I believe that the answer is YES, but couldn't find any example.

Appreciate any hint.

Comment: You could take $H=G$...

Comment: The quotient group G/H will be just G in this case. And what will be dimension of G/H? I'm confusing...

Comment: What is the dimension of a group? Do you mean the order?

Comment: $G/H$ is not $G$, but the trivial group, i.e. the group with only one element. I'm not sure what definition of "dimension" you are using here, but whatever it is, I'm sure the group with one element has finite dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H = 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $G/H \cong Z_2$.